# writing a text file in line by line from the speech recognition method using audio

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I am trying to produce a text file from the speech recognition using audio in *.wav* format. this is to get the subtitle. I already got the text file but the problem right now is the text is produced in a longgggg line.

I want them to be in line by line (maybe after 5 words it will go to the next line) because i want to show up the subtitle in the tkinter windows. as i said I got them already to show up on tkinter windows, only the problem is the text file not producing in lines by lines. pls help me. this is for my final year project as i am still a student of degree.

```
    AUDIO_FILE = path.get()

    r= sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
        audio = r.record(source)

    try:
        filename = ".txt"
        f = open( filename , "w+")

        a = f.writelines(r.recognize_google(audio))
        b = a.split("\n\n") 
        b[:] = (value for value in b if value is not '\t')
        f.close()

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Google error; {0}".format(e)) 

    return filename
```

maybe u guys know how to write an array to produce / writing the text file from audio in line by line. i repeat i want "LINE by LINE".

These are the error that i got. please help me.

```
b = a.split("\n\n")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: will do for the next time. Sorry bcs im new in here. anyway Thank you for edit them for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error on `b = a.split("\n\n")` is because you seem to think that `f.writelines()` will return something. It doesn't, so `a` has the value `None` and can't be split.

The documentation says this about what `writelines()` does:

> **writelines**(*lines*)
>
> Write a list of lines to the stream. Line separators are not added, so it is usual for each of the lines provided to have a line
>   separator at the end.

So, if you want there to be linefeeds in your output file, you have to put them there *before* you call `writelines()`.

But you should not be calling `writelines()`at all, because it expects a list of strings, and `recognize_google()` returns a string.

Since you are getting one long string of words, and you want 5 per line, you need to break the text up into lines with 5 words and call `write()` for each line. Something like this:

```
recognized_text = r.recognize_google(audio)
remainder = recognized_text.split()
while remainder:
    line, remainder = remainder[:5], remainder[5:]
    f.write(' '.join(line) + "\n")
```

Comment: thank you, i tried like this method as u said but it appear to be one alphabet per line. i want them to be appeared like one sentence that contain 5 words and after 5 words it will go to the next line. can u show the array method?

Comment: Edited. I saw your code was calling `writelines()` and stupidly assumed you were passing it a list of strings, which is what it expects.

Comment: THANK YOU soooooo much! you already help me one step closer to complete my final year project. :))))) i got it!